# How can I track a reference with a branch in git?

Tags: git, github

I want to track a Github pull request locally with git as the request is updated (example: more commits are added). Github has a way that you can work on pull requests that come to your repo by checking out the read only refs/pull/.

In other words if someone submits a pull request to my repo I can retrieve that request locally:

```
git fetch upstream pull/123/head:123
git checkout 123
```

The problem comes in when someone then updates that pull request. I can't figure out how to update the local branch because git pull doesn't work to update my local copy:

```
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> 123
```

I've tried:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/refs/pull/123/head 123
git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/refs/pull/123 123
git merge --ff-only refs/pull/123/head
merge: refs/pull/123/head - not something we can merge
```

Comment: It looks like you referenced the wrong upstream branch, I would have expected something like `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/pull/123`. You can check all branch references with `git branch -a` after you fetched from remote.

Comment: You can also run `git branch -a -vv` to check whether your local 123 branch is tracking remote branch.

Comment: @morxa I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? What's the output?

Comment: @morxa error: the requested upstream branch 'upstream/pull/123' does not exist

Comment: Your remote is called `upstream`? What does `git branch -a` show?

Comment: @morxa It shows a number of branches for remotes/upstream but it doesn't show any of the pull refs.

Comment: I've had the same problem and I've detected the branch and create one again using  `git fetch`, since it's remote it mean you can't push there so delete and fetch is the same as pull.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and thought I'd share how I solved it.

The idea of using `--set-upstream-to` does not work, cause the remote reference does not seem to be a branch. That sounds weird, but I think it has to to with where the ref is stored remotely (branches are in refs/heads, but pull requests are in refs/pull).

However, you can add a refspec to your fetch rule for your remote in your git config

```
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

You can even add a git alias that adds a single pr number to your refspecs in your gitconfig (and maybe an alias to remove it when you're done). You can use whatever you want after `origin`, but this is a common choice.

With this, when you do `git fetch origin`, git will also update the ref of the pr. Almost done:

```
git checkout -b pr/${prnum} --track origin/pr/${prnum}
```

Done! Now your local branch pr/123 tracks remotes/origin/pr/123. The latter is a name only valid in your local repo, but it is kept in sync with the pull request branch every time you do a git fetch (including when you do git pull).

Note: a not too old git version should also allow to replace the checkout command above with

```
git checkout pr/123
```

which will create the branch `pr/123`, and correctly set up the tracking for the ref `remotes/origin/pr/123`.

Comment: Very useful! If you don't want to edit `.git/config` manually, you can also use `git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*'`.

Answer (score -2):

```
 git fetch origin pull/123/head:123
```

If this work, that means you are fetching from remote `origin`, not remote `upstream`.

In order to [link the 123 local branch created by this fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309), you would need:

```
 git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/pull/123 123
```

And if someone update that PR, check if said PR was not rebase.
If it is, you would need to fetch the PR branch and reset the local branch.

```
git fetch
git reset --hard 123 origin/pull/123
```

Comment: I'm sorry about that I meant the branch is named upstream I have edited my post to fix that. The problem is the fetch command works for example `git fetch upstream pull/123/head:123` to get a pull request but `git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/pull/123 123` does not, it shows *error: the requested upstream branch 'upstream/pull/123' does not exist*.

Comment: Upstream is a remote name not a branch name

Comment: What does git branch -avv return?

Comment: Yeah I meant the remote is named upstream. `git branch -avv` shows no tracking for the 123 branch, and also there is a bunch of `remotes/upstream/` branches but nothing for pull/123

Comment: That is the issue then: is there a pull/123 branch at the remote repo upstream?

Comment: Well like I said this is a github read only ref so I don't understand what's happening. In other words github creates a pull/<pullrequest#>/head and it works to do `git fetch upstream pull/123/head:123` and then I can locally checkout 123 but I can't use --set-upstream-to to set the upstream.

Comment: I mean: clone that upstream repo elsewhere, and do a git br -avv: do you see a feature/pull/123 in that new cloned repo?

Comment: No I do not see that. As I said I can fetch that ref but I can't track it. Is it possible my git is too old? `git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1`

Comment: It shouldn't, but it never hurt to upgrade to 2.7.2

Comment: Now clone again, but this time, your own github repo, the one to which one does pull request to. Does a git branch -avv shows some pull/123 there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104921/discussion-between-newguy-and-vonc).

Comment: Sorry, got to go to bed :( but for me, those branches should be in the upstream repo.

Comment: It is like this for any repository. For example try `git clone https://github.com/spotify/scio.git` and `cd scio` and `git fetch origin pull/20/head:20` and `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/pull/20 20`.